# When I delete the mail in webmail, it is also deleted from Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I recently installed Outlook 2013. In my older version, it works fine. But in this new version I am facing some problems with it being synchronized with my webmail.

If I delete the mail in webmail, it is also deleted from Outlook. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using an Office 365, Exchange, IMAP or EAS account.  In these cases your local cache is always synchronized against the mail server's copy and this is working as intended. Only POP3 accounts are independent of the server data.